# Will AWS Codepipeline pass symlinks to Codebuild in artifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have some symlinks in my github repo.

When I have a Codebuild project that clones directly from github, symlinks are preserved.

I switched so that Codepipeline listens for changes in my `dev` branch in github, and passes the artifacts to codebuild.

Since making this switch, Codebuild can't see the symlinks anymore.

Is this by design, or am I perhaps missing something in how my codepipeline is configured?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was running into a symlinks issue deploying a node Elastic Beanstalk app. Looks like symlinks is now supported for artifacts. [Check out the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.artifacts.enable-symlinks)

```
artifacts:
  enable-symlinks: yes
```

Adding this to the `buildspec.yml` file solved my issue

Comment: Thanks Tim, this solved my problem when deploying a NestJS app via AWS Code Pipeline > Code Builder > Elastic Beanstalk.

I was getting errors like: `Cannot find module '../commands' node_modules/.bin/nest`

Answer (score 5):

Up to now, AWS CodePipeline doesn't support symlinks in source. Refer to [Source artifact doesn't properly handle symlinks or file modes](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245780) in discussion forums, we can see

> We've got a pipeline setup with an initial "Source" stage coming from a private repo on GitHub. The repo contents get zipped up and end up as the first input artifact for the pipeline.
>
> I've noticed a couple of issues with the zip artifact:
>
> 1.) Symlinks don't come through as proper symlinks but rather text files with the content being the location that the symlink points to.

Maybe AWS CodePipeline team will fix it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody visiting this again, there is a way to do this now. You need to use github connector v2 on your source action, then select "git clone mode".
This will let codebuild clone your repository directly instead of it getting passed through an artifact.

You also need to add the following permissions

Pipeline Role:

- codestar-connections:UseConnection.

Codebuild Role:

- codestar-connections:UseConnection
- codecommit:GitPull

Answer (score 1):

To add detail to the other answers, if all you want is a working `git pull` with symlinks, you'll need to update CodePipeline with `CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF`, pointing to CodeBuild.

Abridged terraform example is below.

---

CodePipeline:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "this" {
  name     = "${var.name}-${var.environment}"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.codepipeline.arn

  artifact_store {
    type     = "S3"
    location = aws_s3_bucket.codepipeline.bucket
  }

  stage {
    name = "Pull-Source"
    action {
      category         = "Source"
      namespace        = "SourceVariables"
      name             = "${aws_codestarconnections_connection.repo.provider_type}-Pull-${var.repo_branch_name}"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeStarSourceConnection"
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = [local.repo_pull_artifact]

      configuration = {
        ConnectionArn        = "${aws_codestarconnections_connection.repo.arn}"
        FullRepositoryId     = var.repo_name
        BranchName           = var.repo_branch_name
        OutputArtifactFormat = "CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Clone-Repo"
    action {
      category         = "Build"
      name             = "Clone-GitHub-Repo"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeBuild"
      input_artifacts  = [local.repo_pull_artifact]
      output_artifacts = [local.repo_clone_artifact]
      version          = "1"

      configuration = {
        ProjectName   = var.github_clone_codebuild_arn
        PrimarySource = local.repo_pull_artifact
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

CodeBuild

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "github_clone" {
  name          = "${var.name}-github-clone-${var.environment}"
  description   = "Clone GitHub Repo"
  service_role  = aws_iam_role.codebuild_github_clone.arn
  build_timeout = var.build_timeout_minutes

  source {
    type      = "CODEPIPELINE"
    buildspec = "./buildspec.yml"
  }

  artifacts {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  environment {
    compute_type    = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image           = "public.ecr.aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:5.0"
    type            = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
  }
}
```

---

CodeBuild `buildspec.yml`:

```yaml
version: 0.2
env:
  git-credential-helper: yes
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
  enable-symlinks: yes
```